# Run Multiple Test case in a Test suite with default authentication

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

I need to run number of test cases from a test suite. Each test case I have a authentication to login from home page. 
Can somebody suggest me on how to keep authentication common for all the test scripts in the test suite.

Comment: If you plan to run in parallel, this approach wouldn't work.  Do you plan to run only sequentially?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the session cookie after the initial login and pass that along with subsequent requests.

Answer (score 0):

How do you run the test cases? by TestNG test suite containg the multiple testcase? If yes then you need to call your authentication function for each test cases.